# Enter method output into class object

Tags: python

I'm trying to directly enter the data that is being generated from `domeinnaamemailadres()` into a specific class object, for example `a`. I want the data to be entered into the domeinnaam attribute. How would I do this?

```
class Customer:
    "De klasse customer"

    def __init__(self, naam, adres, woonplaats, email, domeinnaam= ""):
        self.naam = naam
        self.adres = adres
        self.woonplaats = woonplaats
        self.email = email
        self.domeinnaam = domeinnaam      

    def domeinnaamemailadres(self):
        c = self.email[self.email.find("@"):]


a = Customer('Name1', 'address', 'Utrecht', 'Email1@hotmail.com', domeinnaamemailadres)
b = Customer('Name2', 'Bonestaak', 'Maarssen', 'Bijjaapishetaltijdraakhotmail.com')
```

Comment: Can you please try to use easier to read method and variable names

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the method in that way, since the instance does not exist when you call it.

Probably you want to do something like:

```
class Customer:
    "De klasse customer"

    def __init__(self, naam, adres, woonplaats, email, domeinnaam= ""):
        self.naam = naam
        self.adres = adres
        self.woonplaats = woonplaats
        self.email = email
        self.domeinnaam = domeinnaam
        if not self.domeinnaam:
            #domeinnaam not provided, build one using self.email
            self.domeinnaam = self.domeinnaamemailadres()


    def domeinnaamemailadres(self):
        return self.email[self.email.find("@"):]


a = Customer('Name1', 'address', 'Utrecht', 'Email1@hotmail.com')
b = Customer('Name2', 'Bonestaak', 'Maarssen', 'Bijjaapishetaltijdraakhotmail.com')
```

You can avoid an `if` statement using the ternary operator:

```
self.domainnaam = domeinnaam if domeinnaam else self.domeinnaamemailadres()
```

I'd like to do some comments on your code.

1. First of all, try to write in English. So use english variable names.[`name` not `naam` etc.]
2. Some names are really obscure. What does `domeinnaamemailadres` do? I'd call it something like `domain_name_from_email_address`.
3. The docstring `"De klasse customer"` is completely useless. It does not add any information to the `class Customer` line and it's not in English.

Why should you write in English? First of all because if you don't then how can you ask help in a place like StackOverflow? In this specific case the code is simple enough that I understood anyway, but if things get complex then I wouldn't be able to get what you wanted to do.

Secondly, English is *the* language for Computer Science. It's something you really *must* learn and *use* whenever there is a minimal chance that what you write is read by someone other. I never write code using my mother-tongue(Italian) for this reason.
And even if you think you'll never show the code to anyone, you may always end up with a bug and the need of asking to someone else(e.g. on StackOverflow or on some forum/mailing list) and *bam* they can't help you because they don't understand a word.

Comment: Maybe the OP doesn't use English as a primary language? They can call their variables whatever they want.

Comment: @Aesthete English is not my primary language too, but I never use Italian for code. Otherwise how are other people supposed to understand my code in a situation like this one? Or if the project is open source, you cut out everyone who does not speak your mother-tongue, while English is known by almost anyone(especially in computer-science related environments).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change this line:

```
self.domeinnaam = domeinnaam
```

To this:

```
self.domeinnaam = domeinnaam if domeinnaam else email[email.find("@"):]
```

There is no need for another function there, and you can use the argument as it is still in scope. This will also assign the `domeinnaam` arugment to your member variable if it exists, otherwise it will use the domain name from the `email` argument, allowing you to remove the following checks and function.